# Check for Invalid characters(Special Characters & International character) in file name without validating file path

Tags: javascript, c#, file-upload, filenames, invalid-characters

I am trying to validate a file name with invalid characters in the file name without validating file path. I have tried various combinations but none of my javascript functions seem to do the trick.

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Attachment, new { type = "file" , onchange = "ValidateFileName(this)" })
```

JS:

```
function ValidateFileName(name) {
        if (name.value.match(/\.\.[a-z][a-z][a-z]$/) || name.value.match(/\.\.[a-z][a-z][a-z][a-z]$/) || name.value.match(/^(?!\.)(?!com[0-9]$)(?!con$)(?!lpt[0-9]$)(?!nul$)(?!prn$)[^\|\*\?\\:%<>/$"]*[^\.\|\*\?\\:%<>/$"]+$/)) {

            alert('Invalid file extension.');
            name.form.reset();
            name.focus();
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the regular expression I normally use to validate Windows file names:

```
^(?!^(PRN|AUX|CLOCK\$|NUL|CON|COM\d|LPT\d|\..*)(\..+)?$)[^\x00-\x1f\\?*:\";|/]+$
```

but if your `name` variable includes the file path, you first have to extract the file name out of it using:

```
var filename = name.split(/(\\|\/)/g).pop();
```

or:

```
var name_pieces = name.split('\\');
var filename = name_pieces[name_pieces.length - 1];
```

On a side note, double check the behavior of this part of your code:

```
onchange = "ValidateFileName(this)"
```

because I feel there is something wrong undergoing... I don't know, but something keep on telling me it should be written as:

```
onchange = "ValidateFileName(this.value)"
```

Comment: Splitting the path from the file name was what I was missing. Thank you ! It works now. Also answering your question about this.value , since my JS function actually checks with parameter.value I was not passing in this.value.

Answer (score 0):

In .NET, you can use the [`Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getinvalidfilenamechars(v=vs.110).aspx) static method to get a list of invalid characters. (Note: There's also `Path.GetInvalidPathChar()` for file path characters, which are different).

On the server-side, you can do this:

```
var invalidChars = Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars();
var hasBadChars = filename.Any(c =>  invalidChars.Contains(c));
```

For the JS side, you could output the invalidChars into an JS array server-side, then do something like this:

```
if (invalidChars.some(function(v) { return filename.indexOf(v) >= 0; })) {
    // There's at least one
}
```

Comment: I understood the server side of it. But could you tell me how to implement the JS part. i am just looking to reset the file field and show an alert that there are invalid chars.